# What's wrong with this template

Tags: c++

I am doing c++ 6th edition the 6th exercise of 8th chapter. I have questions on this template. I don't know why it always shows the last string not shows the string that has the max length.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//8.6

using namespace std;

template <typename T> T Maxn(T *,int);

template <>  char * Maxn<>(char **,int );

int main()
{
    double arr_1[5] = { 0.0,3.0,1.0,4.0,5.0 };
    cout << "double max: " << Maxn(arr_1,5) << endl;

    int arr_2[4] = { 3,4,1,0 };
    cout << "int max: " << Maxn(arr_2, 4) << endl;

    const char *arr_3[4] = { "sdf","tttq","ttttrrsdss" ,"q12221"};  
    cout << "char max:" << Maxn(arr_3, 4) << endl;

    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T Maxn(T *p,int n)
{
    T max = p[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (p[i] > max)
            max = p[i];
    }

    return max;
}

template <> char * Maxn<>(char **p, int n)
{
    char * max = p[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (strlen(p[i]) > strlen(max))
        {
            max = p[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: What should the templated type be? Sure you need a template at all?

Comment: I doubt this compiles. Not only because of the odd attempt at a template declaration, but you also discard a `const`. How are you building this? Are you sure your build hasn't failed and you've actually been running an old binary?

Comment: Why do you have a template that doesn't care about types? This makes no sense.

Comment: Note that expected parameter is `char **` while arr_3 is of type `char const **`.

Comment: ***I am doing c++ 6th edition the 6th exercise of 8th chapter.*** Maybe you should cite the exact title of the book.

Comment: This is not a template, but a specialization of a template. Please also show the template.

Comment: I added all code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply start using a debugger or at minimum you could visit your code by using printf debugging. You will see, that your `char*` specialization is never used!

Reason:

Your data type for the "strings" is `const char*` which matches better for the first template than to your specialization and so simply the first template version is called. And this compares now the address of the strings. If your compiler puts the strings in the order presented in the source, you will always see the last string as result, as it has the highest address.

Simply use:

```
template <> const char * Maxn<>(const char **p, int n)
{
    const char * max = p[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (strlen(p[i]) > strlen(max))
        {
            max = p[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

BTW: Your code has some efficiency flows. You compare in the first step two times the same value which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Type of arr_3 is `const char *`, but not `char *`:

```
const char *arr_3[4] = { "sdf","tttq","ttttrrsdss" ,"q12221"};
```

, so the first implementation of Maxn is called, where `strlen` is not used.

Comment: Yes, I see... But how could I initiate  char *arr_3[4] = { "sdf","tttq","ttttrrsdss" ,"q12221"} without using const? I cannot compile it without const char *.

Comment: You actually don't need Maxn implementation  for `char *`. So rewrite it for `const char *` and your code will work as you expect.